# how to change json import file from resource to http url

Tags: android

Hi, this is my code which load Json form resource I want to change this code to load Json from URL what do I do? How I will change this code help me please. I just want to load Json form URL help me please

```
private JSONObject getContent() throws IOException, JSONException 
{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try
    {
        InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedStream = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(bufferedStream);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null) 
        {
            builder.append(line);
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        return new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (bufferedReader != null) 
        {
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Populates the table in the main view with data.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            the read JSON data
 * @throws JSONException
 */
private void populateTable(JSONObject data) throws JSONException 
{
    JSONArray dataArray = data.getJSONObject("observations").getJSONArray("data");
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) 
    {
        final View row = createRow(dataArray.getJSONObject(i));
        table.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                table.addView(row);
             }
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Creates a row for the table based on an observation.
 * 
 * @param item
 *            the JSON object containing the observation
 * @return the created row
 * @throws JSONException
 */

private View createRow(JSONObject item) throws JSONException 
{
    View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.localTime)).setText(item.getString("local_date_time_full"));
    ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp)).setText(item.getString("apparent_t"));
    return row;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

your code is not clear and not getting any idea, you may follow [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) this will really helpful to you.

Comment: not help me.. please edit my code  i want change my json file form resource to url

Comment: When you use Android hive source code (link which Samadhan Medge) pointed ....... the source code has some typo errors ..... be aware while using that source for learning !

Comment: @user2589245: as per you code I'm not get what is the issue, try to explain it more clearly with some extra code and show what is the error in that code. You also study the tutorial first what is JSON and its JSONObject as well as JSONArray then you will surely get how to go further.